# ASP.NET Core ViewLocalizer display key instead of the value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, resx, asp.net-core-localization

I'm working on implement localization in my ASP.NET Core application. My application is multilingual and I want to support two languages (English and Arabic), I followed and configure everything as [this](https://www.webnethelper.com/2022/02/aspnet-core-6-implementing-localization.html) tutorial says.

When I try to used the resource as the following:

```
@ViewLocalizer["WelcomeMessage"]
```

The page display the key `WelcomeMessage` Instead of displaying the value of it `Welcome to our application`

I share my test application on [Github Repository](https://github.com/AYElsharif/ASP.NETCore6-Localization)

What I miss?

Comment: Hi @Abdulsalam Elsharif, any update?

Answer (score 0):

If the `RootNamespace` is different from the `AssemblyName`, include the following in `AssemblyInfo.cs` (with parameter values replaced with the actual values).

Create the `AssemblyInfo.cs` in root project like below:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;   
[assembly: RootNamespace("Multilanguages_App")]    
namespace Multilanguages_App
{

    public class AssemblyInfo
    {
    }
}
```

Besides, your resource file naming need use `.AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)`(**Suffix instead of SubFolder**) to add support for localized view files.